# InvalidPdfException: Invalid object number. at file pointer

Tags: asp.net, itext

Sometimes when trying to generate a pdf file the user gets a blank pdf.
This doesn't happen all the time. 
The error stack

```
    Exception Details
    Type:     InvalidPdfException: Invalid object number. at file pointer 8971
    Exception Class: iTextSharp.text.exceptions.InvalidPdfException
    Message:            Invalid object number. at file pointer 8971
API:        Exception
Thread Name:   <no name-229> <229> <229>

Exception StackTrace
Method               Class      Line        File Name
ThrowError         iTextSharp.text.pdf.PRTokeniser 0              
ReadDocObj       iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader   0              
ReadPdf               iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader   0              
.ctor       iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader   0              
RenderPages     UCPDFPreview  0              
SetControlLayout             UCPDFPreview  0              
RenderPDF         UCPDFPreview  0
```

Comment: How do you create the pdf? How does the user get it? In what code does the exception occur?

Comment: Please check the indention of your code snippet or output. It somehow looks off. Thank you!